# Crear clases dinámicamente, en tiempo de ejecución en java

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, patrones-de-diseño

Hola estoy intentando buscar una solución (quizá patrón de diseño) para poder crear clases en tiempo de ejecución y de ella poder crear objetos. Expongo con más detalle: quiero poder crear especies de animales, todas ellas tienen en común cosas como que todas se alimentan, se reproducen, tienen un habitat,..., y luego quiero poder crear miembros de cada especie. Hasta aquí todo normal, pero lo que busco es poder crear esas especies en tiempo de ejecución y acto seguido instanciar los miembros de la especie que quiera. Me lo he planteado desde el punto de vista de que cada especie es una clase, si alguien ve otra forma mejor, agradezco comentarios. Un saludo.

Comment: No puedes declarar clases en tiempo de ejecución, te aconsejo tener una clase más genérica (Mamífero, Ave... etc) y en cada instancia tener un atributo que especifique la especie

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la diferencia principal entre especies? ¿El cómo hacen en particular esas "cosas en común" ó las "cosas" -si es que existen- que no tienen en común?

Comment: @PabloLozano si se pueden crear clases y código Java en tiempo de ejecución. Sin ir más lejos frameworks ampliamente usados como Spring y Hibernate hacen un uso enorme de esta técnica.

Comment: Si, por el motivo que sea, quieres poder generar código Java (incluyendo la creación de clases) debes estudiar sobre estas bibliotecas: [ByteBubby](https://bytebuddy.net/), [Javassist](http://www.javassist.org/), [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) y [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/). Nunca las he utilizado pero son las más conocidas/usadas para hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: @E.betanzos Sí, pero no es algo básico crear proxies y requiere un uso del API de reflexión que en este caso es una *sobreingenieria* clara. Mi comentario quería decir que no se puede hacer de un modo que valga la pena para el escenario planteado

Comment: @PabloLozano estoy de acuerdo contigo en que quizás para el escenario del OP (que dicho sea de paso no ha explicado el porqué llegó a la conclusión que necesitaba hacerlo) generar bytecode en tiempo de ejecución no sea lo más oportuno. Pero mi comentario trataba de rebatir una afirmación, para mí, muy clara: "No puedes declarar clases en tiempo de ejecución...".

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dices lo puedes hacer mediante interfaces, una interfaz es como una "clase" de la cual solo declaras atributos y metodos de las cuales otras clases van a extender y tienen en comun esos atributos y metodos, pero cada uno los usa y se les asigna valores diferentes, por ejemplo una interfaz animal, atributos: especie, habitad y en metodos: cazar, comer, reproducirse, ahora con esa interfaz creas clases, leon implements animal, tigre implements animal, como podras ver el leon es de especie diferente al tigre y se alimente diferente, eso si, una vez aplicada la interfaz hay que usar todos los metodos y atributos

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta. Lo que el OP quiere es crear la propia clase en tiempo de ejecución, sin codificarla de la manera tradicional.